# Error installing MySQL-python: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mysql, windows

I was trying to install `mysql-python` using **pip**
I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for mysql-python

 ...
 ...

   running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------


Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-
jy5yhb\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-jditig-record\install-record.txt --single-   
version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jy5yhb\mysql-python\
```

Background works did:

- Installed MySQL from official website([link](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/))
- Installed SQLite3
- Installed Visual C++ Redistributable 2008, 2010, 2013, 2015
- Installed C++ Compiler for python (latest)

I have tried all the answers that already exist in Stack Overflow and other Websites, nothing helped.

Context:

I'm trying to run a *Django* server in my laptop, for which I need mysql-python.
(OS: Windows 10)

Comment: I too have the same problem.
I tried installing python from scratch, Didn't work.

Comment: @JithinPavithran I suggest you both to install the precompiled version instead: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Comment: @Selcuk, It didn't work.

Comment: @JithinPavithran What does "it didn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Are you sure you are using the only supported Python version (2.7)?

Comment: @ Yes, Pre-compiled Libraries Does the well